# Docker unable importing cache manifest

Tags: docker, caching, docker-compose, dockerfile, amazon-ecr

I have Docker images, that were pulled from a private repo:

```
docker pull xxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/image/name:base
base: Pulling from image/name
Digest: sha256:3ac2e726336b9048a4bdcc2188bcca0d30e282892f78169939ae42f76c13bd57
Status: Downloaded newer image for xxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/image/name:base
```

Then build image using cache:

```
docker build --cache-from xxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/image/name:base:base -t xxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/image/name:base -t simage/name:base -f Dockerfile.base .
```

Getting caching error:

```
importing cache manifest from xxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.c...
       digest: sha256:7d93b70e81596668b75abedddf217ef3a7dfc0fc4b43141caad899a350105ca3
         name: "importing cache manifest from xxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/image/name:base"
      started: 2020-02-18 11:11:49.478586089 +0000 UTC
    completed: 2020-02-18 11:11:49.706587921 +0000 UTC
     duration: 228.001832ms
        error: "invalid build cache from {MediaType:application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json Digest:sha256:3ac2e726336b9048a4bdcc2188bcca0d30e282892f78169939ae42f76c13bd57 Size:3665 URLs:[] Annotations:map[] Platform:<nil>}"

error on cache query: invalid build cache from {MediaType:application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json Digest:sha256:3ac2e726336b9048a4bdcc2188bcca0d30e282892f78169939ae42f76c13bd57 Size:3665 URLs:[] Annotations:map[] Platform:<nil>}
```

Any ideas on how can I debug this problem?

Comment: do you have the image already build in `docker images` ? can you try building it without the `--cache-from` ?

Comment: @BatchenRegev, yes, the problem in caching, w/o `--cache-from` build is successful

Comment: It seems this is a **problem of the concrete executor node**: Docker version: 18.09.6, Go version:       go1.10.8, OS/Arch:          linux/amd64, Experimental:     false

Comment: @ArtemKhodos could you please share where you found that ?

Comment: I am also seeing same issue. Any way to resolve it?

Comment: Were you able to make this work?